# Reponse в ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, https, response

никак не приходит мысль как конвертнуть стандартный ответ валидации сервер в такой, который нужен мне.
Вот стандартный ответ:
[image: Стандартный response asp.net core]

А мне нужно получить ответ такого рода (желательно что б все ошибки были записаны в одно свойство Error):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Зарание спасибо!!!
Дополнительная информация:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: возможно поможет вам https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125569/net-core-2-1-override-automatic-model-validation

Comment: tCode, да, спасибо, это действительно помогло!